# sort a hashmap in c++ using key. unable to sort

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int flag=0;
    int T,i;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        unordered_map<int,int>h;
        long int n;
        cin>>n;
        long int arr[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
        sort(arr, arr+n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>0)
            h[arr[i]]=0;
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]<0 && h.find((-1)*(arr[i]))!=h.end())
            {
                h[(-1)*(arr[i])]=arr[i];
                flag=1;

            }
        }

        for(auto x=h.begin(); x!=h.end(); x++)
        {
            if(x->second!=0)
            {
                cout<<x->first<<" "<<x->second<<" ";
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            cout<<0;
        }
        cout<<endl;

    }

}
```

Given an array arr[] of N positive and negative integer pairs, may not be in sorted order. The task is to pair the positive and negative elements in such a way that a positive element is paired with a negative element of same absolute value. If a pair element is not present for an element, then ignore it. The output should contain all pairs in increasing order of absolute values. To print a pair, positive value should be printed before its corresponding negative value. Note: The elements in array are distinct. input array = 1, 3 ,6 , -2, -1,-3, 2,7 output: 1 -1 2 -2 3 -3

my code is failing in the test case input array= -1 -2 -5 -6 1 3 4 2 5 6 expected output= 1 -1 2 -2 5 -5 6 -6 my output=6 -6 5 -5 1 -1 2 -2 where am I doing wrong

Comment: If you want an ordered map, use `std::map` instead. `std::unordered_map` is inherently unordered (hence the name), and can't be sorted.

Comment: `long int arr[n]` shouldn't compile. You need to dynamically allocate that array with `long int *arr = new long int[n];`

Comment: @J.Lengel Or better yet, `std::vector<int> arr(n);`

Comment: That's even better ;)

Comment: @Rahul if someone helped with your problem dont forget to upvotem accept the comments and answers.

Comment: Seriously, if you have the test case, you really should be debugging your own code.  Just posting code and asking someone here to debug the code is worthy of getting a downvote.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need all those parentheses in `find((-1)*(arr[i]))`. Write it as `find(-arr[i])`.

Answer (score 2):

To have a sorted map using [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) yields the result. If you are willing to have own sorting function then use a struct wrapper with overloaded `()` operator and remember that container-specific algorithm are better than a generic one.